# mermaidAPI.initialize does not allow to maxTextSize option in Angular

Tags: angular, mermaid

I am trying to call `mermaidAPI.initialize` in angular.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    mermaidAPI.initialize({
      maxTextSize: 1000000,
      logLevel: 'error',
      flowchart: {
        rankSpacing: 10,
        nodeSpacing: 20,
      },
    });
    this.changeContent();
  }
```

I get this error:

> Argument of type '{ maxTextSize: number; logLevel: "error"; flowchart: { rankSpacing: number; nodeSpacing: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'maxTextSize' does not exist in type 'Config'.ts(2345)

How do i fix this so I can build the app?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be that `maxTextSize` was missing from the config interface in `node_modules\@types\mermaid\index.d.ts`

adding `maxTextSize?: number;` solved the issue.

```js
export interface Config {
    /**
     * Built in Themes
     *
     * To disable any pre-defined mermaid theme, use "null".
     */
    theme?: 'dark' | 'default' | 'forest' | 'neutral' | 'null';
    maxTextSize?: number;
```